# Nodejs InputStream Buffer convert to string using python

Tags: python, node.js, buffer, inputstream

i have one application nodejs which request send to python using python-shell npm package. and python script read data and parse string.

nodejs file : teststr.js

```
let buf = `<html><body><p>Reply</p></body></html>`
var PythonShell = require('python-shell')
var options = {
    mode: 'binary',
    args: ['html'],
    scriptPath: __dirname + '/',
    pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python3'
}

var pyshell = new PythonShell('test.py', options)

pyshell.stdout.on('data', function (message) {
    console.log(message)
})

pyshell.send(buf)

pyshell.end(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('End Script' + err)
  }
})
```

Python File : test.py

```
import sys
import base64
import struct
import io

type = sys.argv[1]
html = ""
htmlBuffer = ""
for line in sys.stdin.buffer:
    htmlBuffer = io.BufferedReader(line)


#htmlBuffer = to_str(htmlBuffer) #htmlBuffer.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()
print("%s" % (htmlBuffer))
```

given Output is as below :

```
<Buffer 62 27 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 3c 62 6f 64 79 3e 3c 70 3e 52 65 70 6c 79 3c 2f 70 3e 3c 2f 62 6f 64 79 3e 3c 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3e 27 0a>
```

expect result :

```
<html><body><p>Reply</p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You have probably something wrong in the code of test.py here in the post, because if I run it I get the error:

```
End ScriptError: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

But it does not matter, we can use this simple variant of test.py:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line.rstrip())
```

The point is, that your output is NOT the python output, but it means, that the argument `message` in the `pyshell.stdout.on('data', function (message) {...` is a Buffer object. So (sorry for the error in my previous post) we need to edit teststr.js by adding the `toString()` method.

```
pyshell.stdout.on('data', function (message) {
    console.log(message.toString())
})
```

Then it works. You don't have to worry about buffers in Python.

Comment: no i want to process html using python and send response back to nodejs. currently i received input as buffer in python so how i convert buffer to string

Comment: its given `<Buffer 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 3c 62 6f 64 79 3e 3c 70 3e 52 65 70 6c 79 3c 2f 70 3e 3c 2f 62 6f 64 79 3e 3c 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0a>`